# Dynamic import in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, import, module

How can I make this import:

```
from module import *
```

with `imp` module?

Disclaimer:

- I need use `imp` module because I need make several statements and I want to do it dynamicly
- I need use `*` because I need that in the file I made the import, the variables and methods defined in `module` be available directly, i mean `without module.method` or `module.variable`. And I want import all variables and methods in the module because I don't know what methods or variables can be in the module in the future

Comment: So once you import everything from this mystery module, that you don't know what it contains, what do you plan to do with it? ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to split django settings.py into several files

Comment: Can I recommend this? http://justcramer.com/2011/01/13/settings-in-django/

Comment: Of course you can, but I'm triyng something a little bit different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here!

```
def load_everything_from(module_names):
    g = globals()
    for module_name in module_names:
        m = __import__(module_name)
        names = getattr(m, '__all__', None)
        if names is None:
            names = [name for name in dir(m) if not name.startswith('_')]
        for name in names:
            g[name] = getattr(m, name)
```

I am kind of making things up there a little bit with trying to find an `__all__` symbol first and then, if that files, doing a `dir()` and grabbing symbols that look non-private — you would have to look at the implementation of `import *` to know if that resembles Python's actual logic closely enough for your purposes.

Comment: Interesting, but aren't you devil's advocate by doing `from module_name import *` for several module names at once, skipping all the elements with names starting with "`_`"? Also `dir()`'s main purpose is interactive prompt and they are mentioning in the documentation that its behaviour may vary across releases. But indeed interesting ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django (as mentionned in comments), something like this should work

```
from django.utils import importlib
my_module = importlib.import_module('app.my_module')
from my_module import *
```

But I agree that it may be dangerous

Comment: the `from` syntax will not work with your local my_module. You will get "my_module is not defined" instead. the import_module is analogous to "from foo import bar" so wildcard imports unfortunately won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
from imp import *
```

but remember:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

(from *The Zen of Python* - read it by using the following command: `import this`)

Comment: But I need use the imp module because I need made that import several times

Comment: @diegueus9: I totally do not follow what you are talking about. You can do `import imp` in various locations (every `import imp` statement will be ignored after you first import `imp` module), you can even re-import module using `reload(imp)`. " _because I need made that import several times_ " is not the reason for importing everything, it is not even relevant, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, I think is my bad english, but in the disclaimer I try to explain why just `from imp import *` doesn't work for me

Comment: @diegueus9: Is it about loading modules on the basis of strings you have? Eg. you want something like `import_my_module(name_of_the_module)` instead of ability to call `import imp` anywhere you like in the code?

Comment: Yes, It is. Besides I need emulate `from module import *` and I have a list of modules with strings

Comment: @diegueus9: Then maybe indeed you need to look at [`__import__` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__). Or think about redesigning the way you structure your code (if you have the option).